# undefined symbol: SSLv2_client_method

Tags: openssl

I am trying to update openssl-1.0.1e to 1.0.1s. It's source compile. After I done the following step,

1. cd openssl-1.0.1s
2. ./config --shared
3. make
4. make install
5. apachectl configtest

   I got an error as "httpd: Syntax error on line 55 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_client_method"

I also tried `./config --prefix=/usr enable-shared -no-ssl2`, also it"s same error. Before I installed openssl-1.0.1s, I `make clean` the old one.

Dose anyone know any solutions?

Answer (score 7):

> ... undefined symbol: SSLv2_client_method

It appears `SSLv2_client_method` and friends were accidentally removed from the 1.0.1 and 1.0.2 branches of the library. See [Issue #4398: BUG / 1.0.2g breaks CURL extension](http://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-dev/2016-March/005804.html) dated March 8, 2016 on the OpenSSL developer mailing list.

> Dose anyone know any solutions?

It was fixed with [Commit 133138569f37d149, Retain SSLv2 methods as functions that return NULL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/133138569f37d149ed1d7641fe8c75a93fded445). You should be able to patch `ssl/s2_meth.c` manually with:

```
-# if PEDANTIC
-static void *dummy = &dummy;
-# endif
+SSL_METHOD *SSLv2_method(void) { return NULL; }
+SSL_METHOD *SSLv2_client_method(void) { return NULL; }
+SSL_METHOD *SSLv2_server_method(void) { return NULL; }
```

---

Related, this is not quite correct:

> I also tried `./config --prefix=/usr enable-shared -no-ssl2`

Its `no-ssl2`, not `-no-ssl2`. Also see [Compilation and Installation | Configure Options](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Configure_Options) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Also, `--prefix=/usr` can be dangerous because it usually breaks system utilities that use the system's version of the library. Sometimes the distro applies patches that are not present in OpenSSL's sources (Ubuntu comes to mind).

Usually what you want is `--openssldir=/usr/local/...`. It looks like you built Apache yourself, so you should be able to use it. You can fetch the latest OpenSSL, include an RPATH in the `CFLAGS`, build OpenSSL, install it into `/usr/local`, and then build Apache against that version of OpenSSL. Information on adding an RPATH in the `CFLAGS` can be found at [Compilation and Installation](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: Hi jww, Thanks a lot for you advice. it worked after I tried to patch ssl/s2_meth.c.　will try RPATH later.