# Why won't Anaconda Jupyter Ipython notebook launch?

Tags: python, openssl, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I installed Anaconda on my new machine.  When I try to launch Ipython Notebook (now Jupyter), the browser doesn't launch. I receive the following message in my Terminal.:

```
/Users/jameseaves/anaconda/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
jameseaves (master) ~ $ /Users/jameseaves/anaconda/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jameseaves/anaconda/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 4, in <module>
    import notebook.notebookapp
  File "/Users/jameseaves/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 22, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/Users/jameseaves/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 97, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/jameseaves/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so, 2): Symbol not found: _SSLv2_method
  Referenced from: /Users/jameseaves/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib//libssl.1.0.0.dylib

logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.


[Process completed]
```

---

My OS is El Capitan

Does anyone know what is going wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: See [\[openssl-dev\] \[openssl.org #4398\] BUG / 1.0.2g breaks CURL extension](https://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-dev@openssl.org/msg43232.html) on the OpenSSL dev list. Also see [undefined symbol: SSLv2_client_method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35880228) and [Building ruby with rbenv and ruby-build fails with undefined symbol: SSLv2_method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36286437) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An IT person at my office provided a solution for me.  In particular, I uninstalled homebrew. This is his full response below.  (This may be the same solution as provided by Thomas, but I didn't understand the discussions provided by those links.)

---

The file referenced in your error output,
/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib//libssl.1.0.0.dylib, is version 1.0.0 of the
OpenSSL library. It is being referenced by anaconda and is missing an
expected piece of code (i.e. Symbol not found: _SSLv2_method).

The OpenSSL developers removed _SSLv2_method in version 1.0.2g and fixed
the issue later. So I'm not sure why your version 1.0.0 is having this
problem.

I think that version of the OpenSSL library is from homebrew because the
directory, /usr/local/opt, is not part of a normal Mac OS install. If
you run

$ brew update
  $ brew upgrade

it may fix the problem.

Alternately, I think if you were to uninstall homebrew the problem may
disappear. If you are not using it I would give that a try. Instructions
are here:

https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew

Anaconda should then fall back to the system version of OpenSSL which I
doubt will have this issue.

Be careful though, if you are using homebew that could cause you problems.